# A gerund after "to help"

Tags: gerunds

Is it grammatical to use a gerund after "to help". To me saying: "to help protecting the environment" is  ungrammatical. I would like to get the syntactic explanation.

Comment: _I went to help with the protection of the environment_. _I went to help Peter to protect the environment_. _I went to help protect the environment_. But the participle cannot follow 'help' in that manner. It requires an object (direct or indirect) or an infinitive (either bare or 'to').

Comment: No, "help" does not license (specifically permit) gerund-participial clauses as complement, only infinitival ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the function of MIGHT , HELP and LEAVE here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467833/what-is-the-function-of-might-help-and-leave-here)

Comment: Interestingly, **can't help** behaves differently: << Also, _can't help but_ or _cannot but_: Be unable to do otherwise. For example, • I can't help thinking that the keys will turn up eventually; • He couldn't help but believe he would pass the entrance exam; • I cannot but applaud his efforts. The first of these phrases, _can't help_, is **always followed by a present participle** whereas the others take an infinitive. >> [[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/can-t-help)] 'I can't help serving' ≠ 'I can't help with the serving'.

Comment: Put in a negative and a modal and you'll get very different behavior. _Can help V-ing_ is a construction that's an NPI.

Comment: "I can help opening the window", "I will help opening the window" are fine. "I help opening the window" or "I want to help opening the window" is to me questionable, and I'd prefer "help with", "help by", or something else. I'd be OK with "to help opening the window is one of the duties of a footman", although it's very formal and not the usual way I'd express it.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to use a gerund if the preposition ***in*** is inserted:

- They ask the leader to **help *in* urging** the authority to hold the election on time.

Comment: Hello, hiroshan. Can you add supporting references, quality 3rd-party examples, to endorse this? It appears to be a useful contribution.

Comment: Also, '[V]isit www.haltonhealthimprovement.co.uk/WinterWarmth for more details of the organisations and helplines available _to help **with** keeping your home warm and healthy_ [[Halton BC Press Office](https://hbcnewsroom.co.uk/strategy-launched-to-help-residents-to-stay-warm/)]