# What is the function of MIGHT , HELP and LEAVE here?

Tags: verbs

What are the functions of the following verbs in this sentence?

> It **might help leave** a better impression?

Is *might* a modal? How about *help*? *leave*?

Answer (score 3):

The example sentence mentioned

> - *It might help leave a better impression.*

is already  highly processed syntactically.  First there is the question of what *it* is.

Does *it* represent some activity (like saying "Thank you") that might help leave a better impression?

- *Saying "Thank you" might help leave a better impression.*

Or is *it* a dummy subject inserted by [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299)?

- *It might help leave a better impression to say "Thank you".*

Either one is possible, and in fact they mean the same thing. But we don't know because the sentence is context-free.

As to the structure, it's pretty much the way @Shoe put it:

Might is a modal, followed by an infinitive complement without *to*, which is itself a verb (*help*) that takes an infinitive complement VP, with **or** without *to* -- in this case without -- (*leave a better impression*). That's all, really.

> [`vp` *might* [`vp` *help* [`vp` *leave a better impression* `vp`]`vp`]`vp`].

Comment: In other words... "might" is a modal... "help" is a bare infinitive acting as an adverb... and "leave" is a bare infinitive acting as a verb?

Comment: _Might_ is a modal auxiliary verb; _help_ is a bare infinitive acting as verb; and _leave_ is a bare infinitive acting as a verb. They're all verbs. There are no adverbs. I have no idea where people get the idea that verbs can act as adverbs.

Answer (score 2):

*Might* is a modal verb that is followed by a bare infinitive (*help*).

*Help* is a catenative verb that may be followed by a bare infinitive (*leave*) or a to-infinitive (*to leave*).

*Leave* is the catenative complement of the verb *help*.

You can read about *catenative verbs* on ThoughtCo: [What is a Catenative Verb?](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catenative-verb-1689832)

Comment: In other words... "might" is a modal... "help" is the verb action... and "leave" is a bare infinitive acting as a noun?

Comment: _Leave_ is a bare infinitive acting as a verb. The noun is _impression_.

Comment: Thanks, @John.  Sorry. I see a lot of opinions here on ELL. A casual survey of internet usually yields a bunch more. I get the modal part in this question, but I think the rest is subjective opinion however staunchly held. So, all are verbs still act as verbs, OK.

Comment: A reference to endorse especially the second assertion, please?